# How can I restrict a user from viewing a page that they don't have access to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

I am taking a course that has me creating a basic wiki.  I'm definitely new to this.  I need to restrict users from simply typing in a wiki id that they want to view directly in the URL (example: wikis/5).  The only people who should be able to view a wiki should be the wiki owner, an admin or a collaborator on that wiki.

I have successfully restricted the index view so that a signed in user only sees their own wiki, a public wiki or a wiki they collaborate on.

I have tried to implement similar code in my WikiPolicy, but it isn’t working and I can’t seem to find a solution.  The code I have now simply will show the wiki if the user is logged in.  I know my logic is good, because I can substitute a value for params[:id] like “5” and it works as expected.

```
wikis_controller.rb

def show
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
    authorize @wiki
  end

wiki_policy.rb

def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
    current_wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
    collaborations = Collaboration.where(:user_id => user)
    collab_wikis = Wiki.where(id: collaborations.pluck(:wiki_id))
    collab_wikis.include?(current_wiki)
  end
```

Here is the code that I used in my wiki_policy.rb to return a set of wikis that a particular user is authorized to view.  I believe this works because it is looking at all wikis, instead of being dependent on a particular wiki that the user is trying to view.

```
class Scope
     attr_reader :user, :scope

     def initialize(user, scope)
       @user = user
       @scope = scope
     end

     def resolve
       wikis = []
       if user.role?(:admin)
         wikis = scope.all # if the user is an admin, show them all the wikis
       elsif user.role?(:premium)
         collaborations = Collaboration.where(:user_id => user)
         collab_wikis = Wiki.where(id: collaborations.pluck(:wiki_id))
         all_wikis = scope.all
         all_wikis.each do |wiki|
           if !wiki.is_private || wiki.user_id == user.id || collab_wikis.include?(wiki)
              wikis << wiki # if the user is premium, only show them public wikis, or that private wikis they created, or private wikis they are a collaborator on
           end
         end
        else # this is the lowly standard user
          collaborations = Collaboration.where(:user_id => user)
          collab_wikis = Wiki.where(id: collaborations.pluck(:wiki_id))
          all_wikis = scope.all
          wikis = []
          all_wikis.each do |wiki|
            if !wiki.is_private? || wiki.user_id == user.id || collab_wikis.include?(wiki)
              wikis << wiki # only show standard users public wikis and private wikis they are a collaborator on
            end
          end
       end
       wikis # return the wikis array we've built up
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is not available in the wiki_policy.rb because it isn't passed in the `authorize` method. `authorize` passes the record (so the `Wiki` object that was found) and the `current_user` object. You can skip finding the current wiki again. Also, in this method and others that are actions (`update?`, `edit?`, etc.) you need to return either true or false. So, you need to determine whether or not the user is an admin, collaborator or the owner, according to your specifications.

```
def show?
  record.user_id == user.id or Wiki.where(id: Collaboration.where(:user_id => user.id).pluck(:wiki_id)).include?(record) or user.role?(:admin)
end
```

That will give you a true or false return and check all of the three items you were requiring for authorization. If you want to alter it, you could use if/else statements, just make sure that you `return true` or `return false` on all possibilities.

Comment: Thank you!  This is perfect and helped me understand what I was trying to do better.